# How to dynamically input the location of the background image?

Tags: css, image, reactjs, dynamic

The background differs for each user, therefore I pull the location of the users background from the database and save it in the state as `currentUser.fav`

However when I dynamically fill the background it doeesn't register:

```
<VerticalTimelineElement
iconStyle={{ background: bgCols[i % bgCols.length], color: '#fff',  backgroundImage: `url("${currentUser.fav}")` }}>
```

I've tested that the location works by importing it as `AviationBG` as seen below, which works:

```
import AviationBG from '../assets/backgrounds/aviation.jpg'

<VerticalTimelineElement
iconStyle={{ background: bgCols[i % bgCols.length], color: '#fff',  backgroundImage: `url("${AviationBG}")` }}}
>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle or codesandbox or something, so that i can visualize the underlying problem?

Comment: The location points local or stored in some user defined folder inside your application or server url

Comment: It seems to be right. Please check if `currentUser.fav` returns the correct image location.